# What is the meaning of "one cup"?

Tags: meaning

I read an article about folate, on the link below;
http://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/folic-acid-foods/

When talking about Avocado the article cited, *The most beloved vegetable of Mexican fare, the butter pear, or avocado, holds up to 90mcg of folate per cup, which accounts for appoximately 22% of your daily needs*

full context: *"The most beloved vegetable of Mexican fare, the butter pear, or **avocado, holds up to 90mcg of folate per cup**, which accounts for appoximately 22% of your daily needs. Not only are avocados one of the best foods with folic acid, but it’s also an excellent source of fatty acids, vitamin K and dietary fiber. Adding them to sandwiches or salads will make for an extra-healthy treat"*.

**My Question:** One cup is how much avocado?i mean, how do i know by looking into Avocado that it is one cup? because *per one cup* is mentioned so many times in the article.

by the way, i am not from U.S

Comment: This is more a question about measurements than a question about the meaning of "cup", which can be defined easily with a dictionary. [cup](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/cup) sense 4

Answer (score 2):

While "cup" usually refers to something you hold a liquid in (e.g. "coffee cup"), it is also a [standard unit of measurement in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_%28unit%29). The article you've referenced here is discussing the amount of avocado that would be necessary to fill one "cup".

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments on this answer, one *metric* cup is 250mL, i.e. 1/4 liter, and a cup as defined for US nutrition labels is 240mL. A standard cup is a bit under that (~237mL). That may be a better reference unit for you

Alternatively, the size of a closed fist (of a normal adult) is about the same as a cup, if you're just looking to get a sense of how much one cup is.

Comment: Beat me to the punch; however, please do not confuse the metric cup (250mL) with the customary cup (~236.59mL).

Comment: For the purpose of nutrition labeling, a cup is legally defined as 240 mL.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *[cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_%28unit%29)* refers to a traditional English unit of volume, equivalent to 8 *fluid ounces*, 16 *tablespoons*, or ½ *pint*. In SI, it is equivalent to 236.588236 cubic centimeters.